# не правильно сортирует дату в таблице jquery tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую библиотеку tablesorter, не правильно сортирует дату, нужна помощь, заранее благодарен

```js
$("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter({dateFormat: "uk"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<link href="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.blue.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account ID</th>
      <th>Parcel</th>
      <th>Date</th>
     
     

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>92061</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>12.09.2013, 20:40</td>
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
      <td>7122</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>12.01.2012, 07:09</td>
    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>66571</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>11.11.2012, 12:30</td>
  
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>91999</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>11.09.2012, 08:23</td>
   
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>73070</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>11.07.2012, 00:21</td>
   
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88703</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>11.07.2012, 14:13</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1497</td>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>11.06.2012, 17:40</td>
  
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1497</td>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>31.01.2012, 17:40</td>
  
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Alex , добавил еще один столбец для наглядности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменил `dateFormat` на `"mmddyyyy"`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter({
    theme : 'blue',
    dateFormat : "ddmmyyyy",
    headers: {
      0: { sorter: "shortDate", dateFormat: "ddmmyyyy" }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.blue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>

<table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account ID</th>
      <th>Parcel</th>
      <th data-sorter="shortDate" data-date-format="ddmmyyyy">Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>92061</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>12.09.2013 20:40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7122</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>12.01.2012 07:09</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>66571</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>11.11.2012 12:30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>91999</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>11.09.2012 08:23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>73070</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>11.07.2012 00:21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88703</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>11.07.2012 14:13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1497</td>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>11.06.2012 17:40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1497</td>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>31.01.2012 17:40</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: 13 год залез между 12-ми `31.01.2012 17:40 -- 12.09.2013 20:40 -- 12.01.2012 07:09`

Comment: поправил, добавил в теги th data атрибуты